# Is it possible to ionise matter on big distance from spaceship to reflect it by magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, space

The ship can create a big magnetic field to reflect or catch the ionised particles round it. But non-ionised particles will not interact with this field and still be dangerous for ship passengers.

It is possible to ionise that matter to reflect it too? Will this magnetic field be dangerous for the spaceship passengers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you are in a spaceship with a large Lorentz $\gamma$ with respect to the local hydrogen gas (protons + neutral H + neutral H2 molecules) of number density $N$, then the flux of these particles hitting the front of your ship will be $\gamma N c$ [number/ m^2 sec] because the column of particles in front of your ship is Lorentz contracted in your spaceship frame.  For sufficiently large $\gamma$ this can be dangerous radiation for the ship's occupants and also a drag force on the ship.

As you suggest you solve this problem by placing a magnet far in front of the ship at the end of a long stick connected to the ship.  The magnet should be a "septum magnet" which is a sheet of copper carrying a current in the ship's direction of travel.  This produces an up B field to the left of the sheet and a down B field to the right of the sheet. The relativistic charged particles will be deflected to the left and right of the ship by this magnet. Unfortunately, some of the hydrogen is neutral and won't be deflected.  You solve this by placing a thin sheet of material in front of the septum magnet.  In passing thru this sheet, the neutral particles become ionized and thus deflectable by the magnet .... which is the answer to your question.

The septum magnet is far in front of the ship.  The ship's occupants are not in the field.

Comment: "In passing thru this sheet, the neutral particles become ionized and thus deflectable by the magnet" - I guess, collision with any particle on speed very close to speed of light will lead to a great explosion.

Comment: Why particles bacome ionised when collide with sheet? Is it made from some special material?

Comment: @Robotex :"Electron Stripping Foils" are commonly used at heavy ion accelerators to change the charge state of the heavy ion being accelerated.  The foil may be any material but its Z, thickness, melting temperature, and heat conductivity are design considerations since the high current beams deposit lots of energy while passing thru the foil.

Answer (score 0):

If the ionization will result in unpaired electrons in the atom these atoms will become magnetic. However, since free magnets always attract your "magnetic shield" around the ship will most probably attract and not repel the particles. Of course this is for dielectric, non electrical conductive space-debris or dust particles. If the space particles were to be electrically conductive then the situation changes due to the Lorenz force. Also expect some electrostatic interaction between the ionized space particles and the spaceship.

In general the magnetic shield and ionization of particles idea in practical terms is not such a good idea because the variation in the space particles properties.

A better practice would be to keep the spaceship as possible neutral electromagnetically and don't poke the space particles which mostly of them are in a neutral charge state.

Comment: But collision with any particle on speed close to speed of light will be catastrophe

Comment: I think your proposed solution will do matters even worst. What you need is a deflection field aka ST which will deflect any space particle independent of its electric charge flavor and magnetic properties and which has not been invented yet.   By space particles I'm referring to mm sized or larger particles that could potentially damage a spaceship. Cosmic rays are something else and penetrate almost everything, matter or EM fields. Single isolated cases of atoms or molecules hitting the hull will cause no damage.

Comment: Also relax, vacuum space is much more empty as you probably think. Over the 20 years run of the ISS there were only a handful of  cases reported where space particles actually caused damage to the ISS and it is moving pretty fast too.